# Is it possible to get rid of wait(), notify() and synchronized(obj) {} and use only synchronized methods?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm java newbie and I'm trying to understand java concurency mechanisms.

Say I need to implement any concurency logic with following directives: wait(), notify(), synchronized(obj) {...}, synchronized method.

Is it possible to refactor code without usage wait(), notify() and synchronized(obj) {...}, but using only synchronized method?

For example:

```
public class AppMe extends Thread
{ 
public Counter counter;

static class Counter
{
    protected int num = 0;

    public void increment ()
    {
        num++;
    }
}

@Override
public void run ()
{
    synchronized (counter) {
        counter.increment();
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    AppMe thread = new AppMe();
    thread.counter = new AppMe.Counter();
    thread.start();
}
}
```

could be refactored as:

```
public class AppMe extends Thread
{
public Counter counter;

static class Counter
{
    protected int num = 0;

    synchronized public void increment ()
    {
        num++;
    }
}

@Override
public void run ()
{
    counter.increment();
}

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    AppMe thread = new AppMe();
    thread.counter = new AppMe.Counter();
    thread.start();
}
}
```

This example is pretty simple, but it shows the idea of non-usage of wait(), notify(), synchronized(obj) {...} in thread run context.

Comment: why you need  wait(), notify() in this example?

Comment: @Sainik Kumar Singhal  in this example I don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always *prefer* to write `synchronized(o) { ... }` instead of writing synchronized methods.

A synchronized method, IMO, gets you thinking about synchronization in the wrong way because *methods* don't need synchronization.  No matter what bad thing happens in a Java program, nothing bad will ever happen to its methods:  Bad things only happen to *data*.

If you want to keep out of trouble, synchronize on an object referenced from a final, private variable, with a name that reminds you of what data are being protected.  E.g.,

```
private final Object payrollLock = new Object();

synchronized(payrollLock) {
    doSomethingTo(payrollThis, payrollThat, payrollTheOther);
}
```

The only reason why Java even allows you to put `synchronized` on a method is, back when Java was invented, the authors thought that *monitors* were going to be the silver bullet that would solve all concurrency problems.  A monitor, roughly speaking, is a class whose methods are all `synchronized`.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29  Unfortunately, while that style of programming makes it easy to write *safe* programs, it makes it really hard to write efficient programs.

---

Another reason I don't like to see `synchronized` on methods is, because it tempts you to put code lines in synchronization when they don't need it.

Synchronized blocks always should be as small as possible.  Methods should be as small as possible too, but they have a way of growing over time as developers add a line here, and a line there.

In this example, a programmer has added a line to a method in order to fix a bug.  The new line doesn't need to be synchronized on any lock, so the programmer put it outside the pre-exsiting `synchronized` statement.

```
public void frobbniz(...) {
    ...
    borkWidget.twiddleWith(numBinger, flee);  // Fixes bug 28917

    synchronized(frob_lock) {
        ...
    }
}
```

If the whole frobbniz() method had been `synchronized`, the lazy programmer probably would have just stuck the new line in there anyway even though it did not need synchronization.  Depending on how long a twiddleWith(...) call takes to execute, and depending on what other threads are in contention for the frob_lock, this could have a significant performance impact on the program.

---

Another reason I don't like to see `synchronized` on methods is because it makes the lock object visible to whoever uses your class.  Just search on StackOverflow for all the questions from people who were surprised by what happened when they tried using `wait()/notify()` on a `Thread` object, and you'll see why keeping your lock objects private is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

No. `synchronized(obj)` can be mapped to `synchronized` methods, but there is nothing there that buys you `wait()` or `notify()`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Synchronization is a locking mechanism, so you can get quite far with just synchronized methods (as long as you understand what they really are and do). If you need to make sure that multiple threads can operate on a common object, plain synchronization would suffice.

`wait()` and `notify()` on the other hand are signalling mechanisms. If you need some sort of co-operation between threads and locks, you'll have to use them (actually you should use the higher level constructs, but still). This would mean that instead of threads just sharing a common object, they would actually behave differently depending on what the other threads are doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you use your own classes then in principle you could refactor all `synchronized { }` blocks to instead call a (possibly newly written) synchronized method on the synchronization object instead. However, that's a bad idea, because it will potentially force you to write dozens very specific methods with little reusability value.

Calling two synchronized methods in sequence is also not the same as calling them together from one `syncronized { }` block.  For example, given concurrent `map` the following *is not* properly synchronized and may throw an NPE if multiple threads do this:

```
if (map.containKey (x))
    map.remove (x).foo ();
```

Often it is better to use non-thread-safe objects and synchronize manually as needed, e.g.:

```
synchronized (map) {
    if (map.containKey (x))
        map.remove (x).foo ();
}
```

where `map` doesn't need to be thread-safe itself.

However, a good example where thread safety is an important and useful property are logger objects.